# UIViewController and Asynchronous calls

Tags: iphone, asynchronous, delegates, uinavigationcontroller

I have a controller class that uses asynchronous calls to perform some network operations. My view hierarchy is navigation based e.g. `View1 > View2 > View3`.

Now lets suppose my `View3 (View3Controller)` uses asynchronous calls to perform some network operations, and View2Controller also implements some of the delegate methods as well.

User can use "Back" button to navigate back at anytime, and consequently `[View3Controller dealloc]` gets called. Now i want the async operation to complete! Is there a (safe) way to make sure that `View3Controller` doesn't get `dealloc`'ed until the async operation is completed?

Comment: If the App user does not want the network operation to complete, which is indicated by the user navigating away from the view - why do you want it to complete? Can you not start another connection when I come back to that view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to move the asynchronous call to its own class, preferably owned by `View2Controller` or someone higher up. When pushing `View3Controller` you just pass along this new class and if the user navigates back it will continue as you want.

Imagine an object like:

```
AsyncObject : NSObject {}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
- (void)start;
```

and when pushing `View3Controller`

```
View3Controller *view3Controller = ...
view3Controller.asyncObject = self.asyncObject;
[self.navigationController pushView....];
```

and when starting the async operation from within `View3Controller`

```
self.asyncObject.delegate = self;
[self.asyncObject start];
```

if the user navigates back you could potentially do something like this in `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` in `View2Controller` do get the callbacks from `asyncObject` in case `View3Controller` gets popped.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
  if (viewController == self) {
    self.asyncObject.delegate = self;
  }
}
```

If you need to be able to receive events from the `asyncObject` for several objects at the same time you should look at notifications or KVO (Key Value Observing) instead of using a delegate.

Answer (score 0):

When you push the View3Controller onto the stack, I assume you are creating an instance of it, pushing it onto the stack and then releasing it like:

```
-(void)someMethod {
   View3Controller *vc = [[View3Controller alloc] init];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
   [vc release];
}
```

You could simply omit the [vc release] message until your `-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` is called, then you know you are ready to let go of it?